# Why does this verified JSON Web Token (JWT) output as undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm trying to decode a JWT `id_token` using [jwks-rsa](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa) and [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) but the result is returning as `undefined`.

I know this has something to do with callbacks, and the fact that I need to wait for a response from the `getKey` function but I can't wrap my head around how to structure the code to make that happen.

This is what I have so far...

```
function do_thing(properties, context) {

  const id_token = "REDACTED";

  // Verify using getKey callback
  var jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');
  var client = jwksClient({
    jwksUri: 'https://REDACTED.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
  });

  function getKey(header, callback) {
    client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
      var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
      callback(null, signingKey);
    });
  }

  var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
  jwt.verify(id_token, getKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return decoded;
    }
  });
const bubble_obj = do_thing();
console.log(bubble_obj); //This is `undefined`
```

The `console.log(bubble_obj);` outputs as `undefined`.

I know the problem with the above code is due to the nature of callbacks and asynchronous code, because if I move the `console.log` inside the `jwt.verify` call it will show the correctly decoded token.

See here for that example...

```
function do_thing(properties, context) {

  const id_token = "REDACTED";

  // Verify using getKey callback
  var jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');
  var client = jwksClient({
    jwksUri: 'https://REDACTED.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
  });

  function getKey(header, callback) {
    client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
      var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
      callback(null, signingKey);
    });
  }

  var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
  jwt.verify(id_token, getKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(decoded); //When moved here, it prints the correctly decoded token
      return decoded;
    }
  });
const bubble_obj = do_thing();
```

So how do I make it return the correctly decoded token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not handling the asynchronous code correctly. The `jwt.verify` method returns a Promise if you do not pass it the callback method.

If you use `return jwt.verify(id_token, getKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] })` inside the `do_thing` function and call it like this `do_thing().then((decodedToken) => console.log(decodedToken))`, it should work as expected.

Comment: This now gives an error saying `JsonWebTokenError: verify must be called asynchronous if secret or public key is provided as a callback"` So I tried turning the `do_thing()` function into an async function and made it `return await jwt.verify(id_token, getKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] })` but that didn't remove the error. See working example here: https://repl.it/join/fqcsbnck-twistedsizzler

Comment: I've updated the code on repl.it. It uses the async version of the `getSigningKey`, and has calls the verifyToken method in an anonymous self-invoking function

Comment: It would really help clear things if you read up on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). On a high level, they allow you to work with asynchronous functions without having to pass the callbacks. This makes your code much more clean and readable. A function that returns a `Promise` can be used with either `await`ing it or using `.then()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle promise returned by jwt.verify. either use promise.then. or go with async/await.

```
 async function do_thing(properties, context) {

  const id_token = "REDACTED";

  // Verify using getKey callback
  var jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');
  var client = jwksClient({
    jwksUri: 'https://REDACTED.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
  });

  function getKey(header, callback) {
    client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
      var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
      callback(null, signingKey);
    });
  }

  const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
  return jwt.verify(id_token, getKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] });
  
}

const decodedToken = await do_thing();
console.log("decoded token:", decodedToken);
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `const decodedToken = await do_thing();` is not inside the async function. Therefore it throws an error.

Comment: you have to handle your caller function to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise to verify the JWT with a JWK callback and promise as follows. You will need to wrap the following in an `async` function to use the result of the `verify_jwks()` function:

```js
const token = "REDACTED";
var jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');

// Creates a JWKS Client with a rate limit that
// limits the number of calls to our JWKS endpoint
var client = new JwksClient({
    jwksUri: 'https://REDACTED.com/.well-known/jwks.json',
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 10, // Default Value
    cache: true, // Default Value
    cacheMaxEntries: 5, // Default value
    cacheMaxAge: 600000, // Defaults to 10m
});

// Verifies the JWKS asynchronously, returns Promise
async function verify_jwks() {
    function getKey(header, callback) {
        // Callback that returns the key the corresponding key[kid]
        client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
            const signingKey = key.getPublicKey() || key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
            callback(null, signingKey);
        });
    }

    // Returns a Promise with verification result or error
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
        jsonwebtoken.verify(token,getKey, {
            algorithms: ["HS256", "RS256"]
        },
        function(err,decoded) {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(decoded);
        }
    ));
}
            
let result;
await verify_jwks()
    .then(decoded => result = decoded)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
console.log(result);
```