# How do I verify jwt token with this public key in Node.js?

Tags: c#, node.js, rsa

We have a legacy code that verifies a jwt token with a public key, and it is written in C#. The key is in this format

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "kid": "xyz...",
      "n": "abc...",
      "e": "AQAB"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is deserialised to RSASecurityKey type. The C# then verifies jwt token by assigning the public key to the IssuerSigningKey field.

```
 TokenValidationParameters validationParams =
     new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         RequireExpirationTime = true,
         ...
         IssuerSigningKey = **securityKey**,
         ...
     };
 tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParams, out securityToken);
```

Now I want to port this code to Node.JS and I've been studying this method jwt.verify(token, key). The key param is string type. How do make the original key string to a format that is accepted in Node? Thanks

Edit:

Now I managed to get the original key into this format which seems to be the right one.

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBI...
....
...........................Tf6LHUDEh/hm
7QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

I used this library jwk-to-pem to convert it.

Now I run the verify it shows JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature

Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since we have `kid` field, I suppose you are using multiple keys to sign token and `kid` refers to the key that was used to sign the token. You'll need to fetch the keys (from wherever you are storing them) using the `kid` specified in the token.

Comment: [Maybe related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840319/nodejs-restify-valide-jwt-id-token-with-jwks) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488031/why-does-this-verified-json-web-token-jwt-output-as-undefined) if you have the keys URL. Note that I'm a C# dev so just trying to find something to help you. I can't guarantee that they will work.

Comment: Thanks @DiplomacyNotWar, now I managed to get that key into this format whichi seems to be right format

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ.......
.....
.....
.....KzRIqFxNTf6LHUDEh/hm
7QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Now when I run the verify function it shows: JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out, if you are not very familiar with Node like me, you'll need to use the jwk-to-pem package to convert it to the pem format.

Make sure your signing key and verifying key are the same. Then the verification shouldn't have any problem.